# Non greedy searches with Hpricot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, hpricot

I'm using Hpricot for traversing an XML packet.  For each node I'm on, I want to get a list of the **immediate** children .  However when using

```
(current_node/:section)
```

I'm getting ALL descendant sections, not just the immediate children.

How can I get around this?

Comment: been trying to figure this out today too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `current_node.children`.

Comment: This works, but since it's node based it also gives line endings/return characters: "\n". So you would have to iterate through the result array and pick out just the elements, etc.

Also, it returns the whole element. So if that element has children then `doc.at("element1").children[1]` could return `{elem <element2> "\n" {emptyelem <element3>} "\n" </element2>}` for example. I can't figure out from the original question whether this is a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot/hpricot-basics):

> If you’re looking for a single
>   element, the at method will return the
>   first element matched by the
>   expression. In this case, you’ll get
>   back the element itself rather than
>   the Hpricot::Elements array.

Does the following works for you?

```
current_node.at(:section)
```

If you prefer, you can also use the [xpath child operator](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot/supported-xpath-expressions).

Comment: I'm looking for all the direct children, and those children could be anything

Comment: Yeah this isn't what the question asked - he is asking for ALL children, not the first.